# Any performance reasons to prefer idx() (intarray) over array_position()?

Tags: postgresql, array

Are there performance reasons (or other reasons) to prefer `idx` (from [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html)) over `array_position` to find the position of an integer in a list of integers?

I ask because we've used `idx` since before `array_position` was added to Postgres. It would be nice to use the built-in function rather than relying on the intarray extension, if there is no performance penalty.

Very informal benchmarking suggests it's comparable. PostgreSQL version is 13.5.

Comment: *"list of integers"*? You mean actual arrays, right? Also (always) disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Apologies for my poor grasp of the terminology. Indeed, I mean arrays. Noted that I should always include the PG version. Currently at 13.5.

Comment: Please always put extra information asked for in comments into the body of the question itself - makes like easier than scrolling through comments! Question edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple more or less subtle differences. Some become obvious from looking at the description in the manual:

[The manual about `idx()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#INTARRAY-FUNC-TABLE)

> `idx` ( `integer[]`, *`item`* `integer` ) → `integer`
>
> Returns index of the first array element matching *item*, or 0 if no
> match.

[The manual about `array_position()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

> `array_position` ( `anycompatiblearray`, `anycompatible` [, `integer`
> ] ) → `integer`
>
> Returns the subscript of the first occurrence of the second argument
> in the array, or `NULL` if it's not present. If the third argument is
> given, the search begins at that subscript. The array must be
> one-dimensional. Comparisons are done using `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`
> semantics, so it is possible to search for `NULL`.

- If **not found**, `idx()` returns 0, but `array_position()` returns `null`.
- `idx()` cannot handle **`null`** at all. `intarray` as a whole disallows arrays with `null` values. So it also makes no sense to search for it, you always get `null` when searching for `null`.
  `array_position()` allows `null`.
- Unlike `idx()`, `array_position()` allows an **offset** in the search as 3rd parameter. So you can iterate through arrays to find one match after the other. `idx()` can never find elements past the first occurrence. (`intarray` is mostly optimized to deal with sorted, unique array elements.)
- OTOH, `idx()` accepts **multi-dimensional arrays** (treats them as flat), while `array_position()` does not.
- **Non-standard array subscripts** are ignored by `idx()` (generally bypassing array dimensions and subscripts), but honored by `array_position()`. So **results can differ** for seemingly equivalent, simple expressions! It's best to stick with standard array subscripts, but one must be aware of possibilities. See:

  - [Normalize array subscripts so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011569/939860)
- `array_position()` takes polymorphic arguments, so it works for *any* **array type**, while `idx()` works for `integer` exclusively. There are pros and cons to either. `idx()` is faster with function type resolution, and will never be confused with different types, but it's limited to `integer`: `integer` or die.

All the added versatility of `array_position()` comes at a price. Most importantly, `array_position()` uses `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` semantics to handle `null` values, and that is substantially more expensive. This leads to the possibly most important difference:

- **`idx()` is much faster** and **scales much better** with long arrays.
  (Your *"very informal benchmarking"* mislead you somehow.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b5d1bdda3aed30260c604e60fdc6ba99)* - demonstrating all.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer – thank you so much! I learned a lot. The examples in the fiddle will help me benchmark better in future :)

Comment: @HenrikN: I added one more sneaky difference with non-standard array subscripts.

Comment: I revisited the informal benchmarking – basically, (and I should have made this explicit) that was through the ORM we use, with various overheads that erased differences on the order of 15 vs 2 ms as seen in the fiddle. My conclusion is that the performance benefit of idx is not an important factor for our specific situation – but since we are working with lists of integers and don't need the flexibility of array_position, it still seems the most appropriate choice.